# cpu load balance for "hosting dedicated servers"

Tags: load-balancing, central-processing-unit

sory for my broken English, english is not my native language.

i have been selling web hosts since 2007. ive been using hostgator's reseller packs. i am a totally "newbie" for dedicated servers. thats why i am using reseller pack.

now, id like to buy 3 dedicated servers. cpu usage is my biggest nightmare.

id like to make cpu load balance between 3 dedicated servers. for example: if first dedicated's cpu load is 100%, it must use second dedicated's cpu. if second one's cpu is full too, first and second must use third dedicated's cpu.

well, is it possible? and if yes, how do you call this system (im gonna research on the google)? is it cpu load balancing system? ive been researching on the google for long times and cannot find anything...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your English isn't that bad.

You can't farm the workload around like that.  You basically have two options when you start putting websites on the webservers.

1. Spread the load of the websites out by putting some websites on each of the servers.
2. Put all the websites on all three servers and use a load balancer to balance the traffic between the three machines.

Option 1 will be much easier for you to deal with.  If one of the machines starts seeing higher CPU loads then you just stop putting new web sites onto that server.  Option 2 is more complex to setup and manage but it provides your customers which higher up time and the load is totally balanced across all three of the machines.

Most every hosting company out there uses option #1.

Comment: thank you very very much for your answer. you have been helpfull for me. A+ answer. thanks.. im gonna research details on the google what you said.. thanks.